# Pip cannot find wheels for post release version dependency

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

Pip can't find a dependent wheel file with a post release and dev release segment in the version.

I'm installing `project-a` wheel, which depends on my `library-a` wheel, and both have a postrelease/dev version like `0.0.1.post25.dev0+26d9a21`.
The 2 wheel files:

- `project_a-0.0.1.post25.dev0+26d9a21-py3-none-any.whl`
- `library_a-0.0.1.post25.dev0+26d9a21-py3-none-any.whl`

Here `project-a` depends on `library-a` with version constraints `>=0.0.1.post25.dev0+26d9a21,<0.0.2` (this is generated by `poetry` from `^0.0.1.post25.dev0+26d9a21`

These are installed using `pip` with a custom wheel dir, containing both wheels as follows:

```
python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --find-links=/tmp/wheels/  project-a
```

Results in the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement library-a<0.0.2,>=0.0.1.post25.dev0+26d9a21 (from project-a) (from versions: 0.0.1.post25.dev0+26d9a21)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for library-a<0.0.2,>=0.0.1.post25.dev0+26d9a21
```

However, using **a clean version like `0.0.1` instead of the post-release version does work**.

My post release version seems valid given the version spec https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/, and if I read the wheel spec https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/, it also seems that the post release and development release segment are allowed in the wheel file.

The wheels are created by `poetry`and as expected, the resulting wheel file's `METADATA` contains a line with

```
Requires-Dist: library-a (>=0.0.1.post25.dev0+26d9a21,<0.0.2)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `--pre` to pip install commabd?

Comment: @FlyingTeller thnx, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FlyingTeller mentioned, changing to `pip install --pre`  also works.

---

I used [`dunamai`](https://github.com/mtkennerly/dunamai) to generate the post release version.

I found 2 workarounds by changing the format of the version:

- Running `dunamai from any --style semver`, results in a version like `0.0.1.post25+26d9a21`.
- Running `dunamai from any --no-metadata`, results in a version like `0.0.1.post25.dev0`.

With both these formats, pip finds `library-a` in the resulting wheel of `library-a`.